# Change the text in title-bar of chrome window from [xyz - Google Chrome] to [xyz - Something Else]

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I'm using VirtuaWin and it lets you assign different desktops to different windows based on their title, and I want to assign 2 different chrome processes to 2 different desktops.

Is there a way (extension or a setting) to change the title of a particular window to change it from

```
[xyz - Google Chrome]
```

to

```
[xyz - Something Else]
```

?

Comment: I know this is old, but, you mentioned 'extension' and I recently came across [RenameTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/renametab/mkailnbloeepkajmoblllhhhckpbbncg?hl=en-GB) which lets you rename a tab. Might be useful.

Answer (score 5):

### Update 2021

Chrome v91 now lets you change the full window title. You have to go to **Customise and Control Google Chrome** > **More tools** > **Name window**. A dialogue will open, where you can specify a custom name for the window.

[image: 'Name this window' dialogue]

[image: Custom window title as seen in Process Explorer]

### Original answer

A nice extension to change the title of a tab is to use [Tab Title Tweaker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-title-tweaker/ofmanndkbkkcjolgenmgioploikhkcaa/related?hl=en-GB) (TTT). Right-click on the extension and select options to set some rules. For example, `rename, https://www.google.com, Test` will make the title of Google's tab say "Test".
[Google with a renamed tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPXMb.png)

Comment: How to make this title bar appear at the top of each Chrome window?

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript:

```
document.title='Your website title!';
```

This way you will change the title of the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if the tab's name is the webpage's name then this should work:

1. Right click on the web-page
2. Click 'Inspect Element'
3. Locate to head (should have brackets) and right click the arrow to open it
4. Find 'title' and '/title' (again should have brackets( and delete the words IN-BETWEEN THEM and replace them with whatever you feel like.